# Laravel 4 - Fresh files transferred to cPanel domain

Tags: laravel-4

To make it simple,

I installed laravel on my xampp folder in desktop, once done I've accessed it on my localhost which is working. After that I manually transferred the folder of laravel itself to the domain.

When I tried to access the laravel in my domain, I encountered an error.

[image]

I've checked the file,

[image]

There's no problem, but I'm experiencing an error. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for use `[]` for array started with [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Use `array()` instead and your problem should go away.

You can check your PHP version by running `echo phpversion()`.

Comment: kousha, replacing it with `array()` won't work as Laravel needs PHP >= 5.4 to work. It would be a tedious work make Laravel work on PHP versions < 5.4.

Comment: The problem at hand here is not getting Laravel to work, but rather the problem with PHP not recognizing the `[]` notation for `array()`

Comment: Well, could be both if you read the issue title. I think you could add a small clarification to your answer.